# How can I find out about current Mac OS X games?

Tags: macos

I'm looking for something like http://gamerankings.com/ where I can find comprehensive information about current (and past) games, but for Mac OS X. Not necessarily just a site linking to other reviews, but it shouldn't be a time sink like normal gaming sites, either.

http://apple.com/games/ and http://insidemacgames.com/reviews/ come to mind, but the former seems to be either incomplete or outdated, the latter very puzzle- and casual-heavy.

Comment: +1 Blizzard games can't be the only good games for this platform

Comment: Apple links to a bunch of stores that sell games which usually have up to date lists.

I know you can get DA:O for mac.

Comment: I would love to see something like Rock, Paper, Shotgun for Mac games... http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steam has started supporting and distributing Mac games a couple of months ago. You can use the [Advanced Search](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?term=) to filter by OS. At the time I am writing there a `138 games and 18 DLC` for Mac listed there.

On 19 June 2010, Appstorm.net wrote an article about [50 Games for Mac](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/games/the-giant-list-of-50-mac-games/).

Wikipedia has a [long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Macintosh_games) as well.

**Pay attention that not all games run on all Mac models. Check the requirements before buying them.**

Comment: Thanks for the appstorm article! However this is something you typically only find when regularly reading sites like that. While it helps quite a bit now, it will, unfortunately, become outdated rather quickly.

As for the wikipedia list, it's completely neutral regarding ratings and also does not list be year or even decade, so requires quite a bit of time in that regard.

Comment: I really love your steam search link -- they also show the metascore from Metacritic there, which is fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted answer, since AppStorm is very useful currently at least, and I love the Metacritic info right in the Steam list (although not the first answer with Steam)

Answer (score 9):

Have you taken a look at [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/)? There are quite a few games for OS X and they seem to be adding more and more. They have a nice community forum.

Comment: Steam is a great source for Mac games at the moment and they often have really good deals on.

Answer (score 2):

GiantBomb's games list, [filtered for the Mac platform](http://www.giantbomb.com/games/?filter_type=platform&filter_value=MAC) might be a good place to start. Since it's a wiki, everything stays pretty nicely updated even if it's an old game that's been ported through Steam or some other intermediate platform.

Comment: The site looks good, but I get the impression it's incomplete: 5 games in one and a half years? Really?

Comment: It's filtered by default to popular titles. You should be able to play with the settings so it shows all games.

Comment: You're right -- [this list](http://www.giantbomb.com/games/?sort=release_date&filter_type=platform&filter_value=MAC) is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

This question was quite a while back but there's also the [Mac App Store](http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/) now, which has a game category of it's own. To be fair, there are lots more mini-games (think iPhone game turned desktop) than full-size games, but a couple high-profile games like Call of Duty 4 made it in for the launch and surely there will be more soon.

Comment: True, but then again it's a store. I didn't link to MacGameStore in my initial post either. I'd like to see high-quality reviews, not just the two-liners people post on the stores.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is one "end all" site for all known OS X games, but an additional source to consider is [Steam Mac section](http://store.steampowered.com/browse/mac). There isn't a huge selection yet, and it's mostly Valve's own games, but the list is growing each week.

One nice thing about Steam is that if you buy a game, you can play it on all supported platforms without buying an additional copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a place to buy older PC games that may or may not run on the Mac I would checkout [gog.com](http://gog.com). They seem to some how get publishers to port most of their games to OSX

Reasons why I love gog.com:

- You buy it. You own it. 100% DRM-free.
- You get awesome content (soundtracks, wallpapers, manuals, videos, etc)
- Extra compatibility (Window XP or later, Max OSX 10.6.8 or later)

Now if they could get ATARI to port Roller Coaster tycoon already.

Comment: The buying isn't as difficult as the finding. Still, since gog added the "Mac" category it's become somewhat helpful. But unfortunately they don't show me which of my 317 games can be played on the Mac I'm using right now -- it's simply missing a filter option for the library ([1](http://www.gog.com/wishlist/site/sort_games_by_platform_windows_osx_linux) [2](http://www.gog.com/wishlist/site/option_to_filter_games_by_platform_pc_mac)).